# Get dynamic Id from dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have div element with dynamic Id.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="elmn1"></div>
    <div id="id-has-changed"></div>
    <div id="elmn3"></div>
    <div id="elmn4"></div>
    <div id="id-has-changed-by-user-from-input-field"></div>
</div>
```

All element `id` (except #parent) are editable by user from an input field, so the last child of #parent may has new id set by user.

I want to check the element with the highest  number (`4`) at the last part of their `id` and I want to append a new element with the next `id`.

```
var nextId = "elmn" + (numberOfLastElement + 1);
var newElmn = document.createElement("div");

newElmn.id = nextId;
document.getElementById("parent").appendChild(newElmn);
```

In this paricular case the new element will has `id="elmn5"`.

My question is, how to get `numberOfLastElement`?

Comment: Is the hightest number always the last element that starts with this id? If not, you will have to loop through all elements to find the hightest id

Comment: if its always the last one, you just have to append to your div `parent`

Comment: No, user can changes any id from input field, so the last element can has new id set by user.

Comment: Fixed my answer. It's still more limited than the excepted one. So I'm leaving it here just as a syntax alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Updated

[Final version of Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95h7b6ce/2/)

```
var myEl = document.getElementById('parent').children;
var highest = null;
var idName= null;

if (myEl){

for (var ii=0;ii<myEl.length;ii++){
     
     var temp = myEl[ii].getAttribute('id');
    
    
    var intval = temp.match(/\d+/g)
     
    
    if (intval !=null){
        
        if(intval>highest){
            
         
            highest = intval;
            idName = temp;
        }
        
        
    }
  

  }

}

console.log(idName);
```

### Leaving the code below for historical info

Here is a [working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95h7b6ce/).

```
var myEl = document.getElementById('parent').children;
var count = 0;
      if (myEl) {
            var match = 'elmn';
            for (var ii = 0; ii < myEl.length; ii++) {
                var temp = myEl[ii].getAttribute('id');
                if (temp.indexOf(match) == 0) {
                    count++
                }
            }
        }
        alert('count is ' + count);
```

Comment: I believe OP wants new element to have id elmn5 not elmn3 as your suggested solution

Comment: Indeed. It's a little unclear in the question. I am editing now. But he SHOULD be able to solve it from here. :)

Comment: Thanks for accepting. Note, there is a bug which I am fixing shortly. Check back in two minutes for an update.

Comment: Thanks @E.Maggini you resolve it with a short of code.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the logic:

Get all the elements what have `id="elmnx"` where x=1,2, etc. `$("[id*='elmn']")`

Get the last of them. `last()`

Get its id.`attr('id')`

Substring to get the number at the end. `substring(4)`

Make it an int so that you can add +1. `parseInt()`

Try:

```
var numberOfLastElement=parseInt($("[id*='elmn']").last().attr('id').substring(4));
```

Comment: I believe OP is trying to find any dynamic element ending in a number and then find the highest one. :)  Additionally, this solution requires the addition of jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, assuming `elmn` prefix in all applicable IDs:

```
function MaxElemNo() {
  var prefix = "elmn";
  var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
  var elements = parent.querySelectorAll("[id^='"+ prefix + "']");
  var lastElemNo = 0;
  for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
     var el = elements[i].id;
     var num = + el.substring(prefix.length, el.length);
     lastElemNo = Math.max(lastElemNo, num) 
  }
  return lastElemNo;  
}    
console.log(MaxElemNo());
```

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/95h7b6ce/13/)