# Get dynamic Id from dynamic elements and click

Tags: javascript

I have one problem that I cannot solve, 
I was searching for a solution but nothing I have found fits my needs.

I have this code:

```
<a class="button-main" id="saveButton7" href="#" onclick="window.location.reload()">Save</a>
```

Where saveButton is static part and only number changes dynamically .

I need to get that id and click on it:

```
document.getElementById("saveButton7").click();
```

I have tried things like this: [Get dynamic Id from dynamic elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180810/get-dynamic-id-from-dynamic-elements)
But it does not work because I need to get whole id and click on it.

Thanks

Comment: Why not get the element by its class ?

Comment: You could use a local javascript variable to denote the current number? And just append it every time something like `"saveButton"+num`.

Comment: Because I have more of them and I need this one, the goal is to make a keyboard shortcut to click on specific button

Comment: jQuery available? Use another event for this, it's called `keydown`. Just bind the same functionality to it, checking `keycode` to match the key pressed.

Comment: @Marin I would like you to edit your question to your actual problem and then I have a very simple solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you try jQuery selectors:

```
    $("[id^='saveButton']").click();
```

The ^ represents any attribute whose id starts with **saveButton**

**EDIT 1**

Then you could have something like this:

```
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a"), item;
    for (var i = 0, len = anchors.length; i < len; i++) {
      item = anchors[i];
      if (item.id && item.id.indexOf("saveButton") == 0) {
         // item.id starts with saveButton
      }
     }
```

**EDIT 2**
Have a look @ this

```
    <a class="button-main" id="saveButton7" href="#" onclick="onClickFunction(event);">Save</a>


    function onClickFunction(event){
           var saveButtonObject = event.target;
           //do reloading stuff here...
    }
```

The event object is implicitly passed by the browser here...

Comment: Thanks, it works like this, I was using java script only and did not look at jquery, my mistake

Comment: This is probably **not** the solution you want, since this will create a click on **every** element whose `id` starts width `saveButton` - not only on `#saveButton7`, but also e.g. on `#saveButtonDisabled`, `#saveButton3` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below:

```
$('a[id^="saveButton"]').click();
```

It'll find "A" tag in your html page that starts with "saveButton", then call it's onClick event.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you would like to have each such `<a>` element to be triggered with a keyboard event. You could do something like this in `HTML5`,

```
<a data-keybind='KEY_HERE' ..>Save</a>
```

Now, using `jQuery`:

```
$('#DOMelement').on('keypress',function(e){
    $("a[data-keybind='"+e.which+"']").trigger('click');
});
```

Such kind of event handler could be used.
Essentially I am using `jQuery` [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).